# postgresql: is possible to rename a table from db1 to db2?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, table-rename

On mysql supposing I want to rename table buildings from db1 to db2

```
rename table db1.buildings to db2.buildings;
```

On postgres I known how to rename a table inside the same db

```
alter table buildings rename to newbuildings;
```

Is possible to rename from db1 to db2 on postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution

```
pg_dump db1 -t buildings| psql db2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ALTER TABLE SET SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE db1.buildings SET SCHEMA db2;
```

Comment: Didn't know this one. Can come in handy +1

Comment: This command move from one schema to another schema, if the schema are in the same db works otherwise not